# std::vector of class with private constructor does not compile when using modern C++

Tags: c++, c++17

The code I'm working on was initially designed using `C++03`, and compiles and functions without errors using `g++ -std=c++03`. My goal is to have the same code compile using `g++ -std=c++17`.

The code contains a `MyClass` which contains a `NestedClass`. Only `MyClass`should be able to use, create, and modify instances of `NestedClass`, which are stored in a `std::vector< NestedClass >`. As such `NestedClass` contains a private constructor, and declares `MyClass`  and `std::vector< NestedClass >` as friends.

Minimal Example:

```
#include <vector>

class MyClass {

    public:

        class NestedClass {
            friend class MyClass;
            friend class std::vector< NestedClass >;
            double _d;
            NestedClass( double d = 0.0 ) : _d(d){ }
        };

    private:

        std::vector< NestedClass > data;

    public:

        MyClass(){
            data.resize( 40 );
        }


};

int main(){
    MyClass myclass = MyClass();
    return 0;
}
```

This minimal example fails when compiling `-std=c++17` with the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = MyClass::NestedClass; _Args = {}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:527:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = MyClass::NestedClass*; _Size = long unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:583:20:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = MyClass::NestedClass*; _Size = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:645:44:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = MyClass::NestedClass*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = MyClass::NestedClass]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:563:35:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_append(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = MyClass::NestedClass; _Alloc = std::allocator<MyClass::NestedClass>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:692:21:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::resize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = MyClass::NestedClass; _Alloc = std::allocator<MyClass::NestedClass>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
bug.cpp:21:20:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: ‘MyClass::NestedClass::NestedClass(double)’ is private within this context
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bug.cpp:11:4: note: declared private here
    NestedClass( double d = 0.0 ) : _d(d){ }
```

How can I rewrite the code so that it compiles using c++17?

Changing `std::vector< NestedClass >` to `std::vector< NestedClass * >` is not an option since it would require rewriting code that uses `MyClass` which I do not control.

Comment: Can't you just make the constructor for NestedClass public?

Comment: I have the same error in any version of c++.

Comment: It works - [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/SnYpca)

Comment: _"Only MyClass should be able to use create and modify instances of NestedClass"_ I then think your intention will be met if `NestedClass` is inside `private` section of `MyClass` but members of `NestedClass` themselves are `public`.

Comment: @Bartek Not with the compiler version and command line options (presumably) being used by the OP, see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/ZNBCJA).

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, of course. Its misunderstanding. It was answer to SHR's comment, but I forgot to add "sometimes" to my comment :)

Comment: @Bartek OK, then please use "@" to make your intentions clear next time, thx.

Comment: @divinas That would be a possible solution, but I'd rather keep the same behavior that was implemented for the old version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The minimalistic fix for your particular example is

```
data.resize( 40, {} );
```

Call the private constructor yourself, so that `vector` only needs to call the  (implicitly declared) public ones.

---

In general, befriending something in a library you don't control doesn't work. You have no idea whether said something is actually going to delegate the work to something else.

In `vector`'s case, it is pretty much required to delegate said work to something else.

---

A proper fix will likely involve changes to the classes involved. One possibility is the passkey idiom: make the constructors public, but only callable with an argument of a private type.

Comment: The minimalistic fix works for the minimal example. I will try to implement in the Actual code and Hopefully will not have any issues.

Comment: I was able to fix the code following your suggestion. I removed the `friend std::vector< NestedClass >` declaration since it is now useless, and instead of using the list initializer `{}` i explicitly call `MyClass::NestedClass()` and this way the code will compile both with modern C++ and the old version. Thank you for your help.